# Is "du bist dran" the best translation for "it is your turn"?

Tags: translation

Is there a more direct translation of "*it is your turn*"?

I have used "*du bist dran*" for card games and the like, but is that a good translation in general? For example how would you translate "*it is your turn to do the dishes*"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Du bist dran.

Yes, that's a good translation for a colloquial sentence (the expression *dran sein* is colloquial for *an der Reihe sein*).

Your example sentence:

> Du bist dran Geschirr zu spülen.

---

Alternatively:

- Du bist an der Reihe
- Du kommst dran

> Du bist an der Reihe Geschirr zu spülen.

Comment: +1 good answer. In german you shouldn't forget the honorific version: "Sie sind dran" or "Sie sind dran Geschirr zu spülen". Even though it doesn't makes much sense in this example.

Answer (score 4):

Für mich ist das die korrekte Übersetzung.
Deinen Beispielsatz würde ich folgendermaßen übersetzen:

> Du bist dran mit Geschirr spülen.

Comment: Wird hier "Geschirr spülen" nicht zusammengesetzt als Hauptwort geschrieben, da es mit einer Präposition verwendet wird: "mit [dem] Geschirrspülen"?

Comment: @splattne das ist so eine gebräuchliche umgangssprachliche Formulierung in D, aber grammatikalisch nicht wirklich korrekt

Comment: Oder auch "Du bist mit Geschirrspülen dran."

Comment: @Pekka: Wär's ohne Leerzeichen vor "spülen" nicht korrekt?

Answer (score 4):

"Du bist dran" is the best translation in the sense that it covers most cases of "it is your turn".

More close translation would be:

"Du bist am Zug." or "Dein Zug."

but this would not be appropriate for dish-washing. This would apply to games where you actually move something during the turn (think chess) and to situations where the phrase includes a challenge e.g. in a discussion you demolish all arguments of your opponent and then add "now it is your turn".

Comment: I would translate "Du bist am Zug" with "(It's) your move!" It does indeed have a strong game connotation and will hardly be used outside of that context.

Answer (score 3):

As swegi has pointed out already, *Du bist dran* is perfectly fine, both for games and in general. "It's your turn *to...*" can be usually translated as "Du bist dran *mit...*" (+ dative). If you are looking for alternatives, there's always *Du bist an der Reihe*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

As regards washing the dishes, I would say:

> Du bist mit dem Geschirrspülen dran.